# webpage to html without source

Tags: web-applications

I am trying to find if it is even possible.

I have a web page and the source is not available. basically it does not show the html of what is displayed.

I want to somehow create an html based on what is displyed on the page. Of course it wont be accurate but to a large extent it can show the page would be sufficient.

any idea how can we achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java robot api of java.awt libraries can be used to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), in the HTML tab, right-click on the `<html>` tag and click "Copy HTML".

Comment: Thanks but looking for a programmatic solution to achieve the same

Comment: anyone else on this plz?